# How does gradle choose certain urls to look in for a repository? How do I point it in the right direction so that I can import this JAR?

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, gradle, commonsware-cwac

In order to fetch the cwac-camera commonsware jar, I have this in build.grade:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:camera:0.6.+'
}
```

when I try and compile, it gives me this:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.commonsware.cwac:camera:0.6.12.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/commonsware/cwac/camera/0.6.12/camera-0.6.12.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/commonsware/cwac/camera/0.6.12/camera-0.6.12.jar
         file:/home/alex/android/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/commonsware/cwac/camera/0.6.12/camera-0.6.12.pom
         file:/home/alex/android/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/commonsware/cwac/camera/0.6.12/camera-0.6.12.jar
         file:/home/alex/android/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/commonsware/cwac/camera/0.6.12/camera-0.6.12.pom
         file:/home/alex/android/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/commonsware/cwac/camera/0.6.12/camera-0.6.12.jar
     Required by:
         Cwac4:app:unspecified
```

so its looking in jcenter, and in a bunch of my home directory files and failing to find anything. I think it should look on github as I know there are releases here: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/releases, so how can I tell it that?

additionally, when I manually include the jar in one of my home directories for instance, it compiles with no errors, but using import `com.commonsware.camera..`(anything basically) results in "could not resolve symbol commonsware" errors. I take this to mean that I can't just manually put it somewhere and that perhaps android studio needs to see it in an official repository for it to allow importing it. Is this correct?

NOTE: I know that this library is slated to be rewritten. I would like to use it anyways if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> so how can I tell it that?

Quoting [the current version of the documentation](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera#installation):

> To integrate the core AAR, the Gradle recipe is:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:camera:0.6.+'
}
```

You appear to have added the `dependencies` but did not update your `repositories`.

Comment: oh I thought it was gradle or maven as in you choose between those 2. ok thanks! Ill try it later today

Comment: @BigBoy1337: Here, `maven` is referring to a Maven-style artifact repository (as opposed to Apache Ivy or other repo structures).

Comment: I have integrate this demo:https://github.com/jaydeepw/poly-picker  and this show me error like fail to resolve com.commonsware.cwac:camera:0.6.+

Comment: @Rajat: CWAC-Camera has been discontinued. I do not recommend using any code that depends upon it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 repositories {
        maven { url 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }    
        maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com" }
    }
```